# Can I use Elder Charm of Good Fortune for offspec gear?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria, an item called 'Elder Charm of Good Fortune' has been added to the game. The purpose of this item is that once you kill a raid boss or world boss, regardless of difficulty, you will be presented with the opportunity to perform your own personal roll for a chance at additional loot.

If for whatever reason I have use my off spec for a fight, am I able to use these charms to roll for gear for my other (main) spec or are they limited only for the currently activated spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Patch 5.3, there is a Loot Specialization submenu accessible by right-clicking your portrait.

[image]

Using this menu, you can specify which spec you want to receive loot for, instead of being limited to just your current spec.